# Fixing smb login, disk permissions, and remote access

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, mac, vnc

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to replace my Hackintosh setup because my ZFS drive had slow connections. Since switching over, data seems to be transferring much smoother so I'm very happy. However, there are a few things I cant fix:

1. When I connected to Ubuntu via the Mac, I couldn't sign in and had to use Guest Access to get into the Ubuntu computer. Is there a way to set it up so that the login works? I don't want to give random strangers access through the guest account.
2. I can't access my iPhoto library from my Mac that I'm connecting via smb because I don't have permissions. How would I go about fixing this?
   My `smb.conf` file is:

   ```bsh
   #
   # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
   #
   #
   # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
   # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
   # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
   # are not shown in this example
   #
   # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
   # commented-out examples in this file.
   #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
   #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
   #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
   #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
   #    enough to be mentioned here
   #
   # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
   # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
   # errors. 

   #======================= Global Settings =======================

   [global]

   ## Browsing/Identification ###

   # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

   # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
       server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

   # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
   # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
   #   wins support = no

   # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
   # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
   ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

   # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

   usershare owner only = false

   #### Networking ####

   # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
   # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
   # interface names are normally preferred
   ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

   # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
   # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
   # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
   # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
   # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
   ;   bind interfaces only = yes



   #### Debugging/Accounting ####

   # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
   # that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

   # If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
   # parameter to 'yes'.
   #   syslog only = no

   # We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
   # should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
   # through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

   # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


   ####### Authentication #######

   # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
   # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
   # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
   # directory domain controller". 
   #
   # Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
   # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
   # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
   # new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   # If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
   # password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
   # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
   # passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

   # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
   # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
   # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
   # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
   # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

   # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
   # to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

   ########## Domains ###########

   #
   # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
   # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
   # or 'domain logons' is set 
   #

   # It specifies the location of the user's
   # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
   # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
   # below)
   ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
   # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
   # (this is Samba's default)
   #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

   # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
   # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
   # point of view)
   ;   logon drive = H:
   #   logon home = \\%N\%U

   # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
   # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
   # in the [netlogon] share
   # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
   ;   logon script = logon.cmd

   # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
   # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
   # password; please adapt to your needs
   ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

   # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
   # SAMR RPC pipe.  
   # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
   ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

   # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
   # RPC pipe.  
   ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

   ############ Misc ############

   # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
   # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
   # of the machine that is connecting
   ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

   # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
   # for something else.)
   ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
   ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
   ;   template shell = /bin/bash

   # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
   # with the net usershare command.

   # Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
   ;   usershare max shares = 100

   # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
   # public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

   #======================= Share Definitions =======================

   # Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
   # to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
   # user's home directory as \\server\username
   ;[homes]
   ;   comment = Home Directories
   ;   browseable = no

   # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
   # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
   ;   read only = yes

   # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
   # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   ;   create mask = 0700

   # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
   # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   ;   directory mask = 0700

   # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
   # with access to the samba server.
   # Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
   # can connect to \\server\username
   # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
   ;   valid users = %S

   # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
   # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
   ;[netlogon]
   ;   comment = Network Logon Service
   ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
   ;   guest ok = yes
   ;   read only = yes

   # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
   # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
   # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
   # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
   # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
   ;[profiles]
   ;   comment = Users profiles
   ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
   ;   guest ok = no
   ;   browseable = no
   ;   create mask = 0600
   ;   directory mask = 0700

   [printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

   # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
   # printer drivers
   [print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
   # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
   # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
   # admin users are members of.
   # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
   # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
   ;   write list = root, @lpadmin
   ```
3. How does remote access work with Ubuntu? I tried `vncserver` but I couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 3):

I can answer the last two questions, the first question is a little vague, what do you mean by *"When I connected to Ubuntu via the Mac, I couldn't sign in"*, how are you trying to sign in?

1) Please clear up how you are trying to sign into Ubuntu from your mac!

2) Assuming its telling you that you don't have file permissions as opposed to access to the share, try using the command 
`sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder`
and see if that gives the desired  outcome, if the issue is that you don't have access trying creating a user account using the command `sudo smbpasswd -a YOURUSERNAMEHERE` and the set a password for the account.

3) If you mean remote access to use the Ubuntu terminal I would use open-ssh which you can install by typing `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` you can then use the mac terminal to connect to your Ubuntu machine using your log on details (see this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equivalent-of-PuTTY-for-Mac-OS-X) for a vague explanation). If you wish to use the GUI try installing [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) on both the mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: When I use the "Connect to server" option on OSX Finder and after i type in smb//IPaddress, I'm prompted to sign into the Ubuntu or choose the guest access. I tried using my Ubuntu password but it didn't work. How would I fix the login and also disable the guest access?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use a Mac so can't be any help there, have you tried using team viewer I think it could be a much more hassle free approach, you can setup un-attended access with one user ID and then a password you set up, if you remember to log off you Ubuntu machine after every session you will be asked to log in again when you connect via team viewer

Comment: Also going back to the sudo chmod -r 755 /path/to/folder command, it doesnt seem to be working for me... i get the error that 'chmod cannot access '755' no such file of directory. Any fixes?

Comment: Apologies it should be capital a capital in the argument, i have update my answer to show this.

Comment: So that worked. However, I still can't seem to write anything to the folder from my mac now... I'm connected through the server via my user account and password now if that makes a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please explain how you are connecting to the server, which method of the above are you using? What is the path that you are trying to write images to? is it in your home directory the path would begin with something like "~/" or "/home/YOUR USERNAME".

Comment: I'm connecting via Mac OSX Finder "Go to Server" via smb://IPADDRESS. Then I'm logging into my user account with the password set using the smbpasswd command from your original answer. I changed the permissions for the whole ZFS drive so I assumed that everything inside the drive would have its permissions changed. The folder I'm trying to write the images to is within the ZFS drive.

Comment: So I've been playing around again with the folders and I think the problem is that when I use smb to get inside Ubuntu, I don't access the computer as a user. Is there anyway I can get access into Ubuntu using smb from a Mac?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but have you tried adding the samba user as described in the answer ? Can you put your samba config file in your question.

Comment: Hey no problem about the questions. I appreciate you taking the time to walk me through this as I really have no clue what I'm doing. And yes, I did add the samba user using the `sudo smbpasswd -a YOURUSERNAMEHERE` command. I'm at work now but when I get home, I'll put my config file in the quesiton. If I recall correctly, I did make one change in it to allow me to share the folder via smb.

Comment: Did you put your own user name in ? Okay no worries

Comment: Yeah I did put my own username and I created a password for it. I'm still not sure what's going on. I added smb config to the question up top. I can't figure out how to format the post so that it turns into code... Let me know if there's anything I can do to make it read better...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your folders in Ubuntu that are shared via right click, after that do a sudo smbpasswd -a (user) and set password and reboot.